# Error while saving the jwt token using auth0

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, auth0

Error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: 
Service not found: http://localhost:8000     
at new OAuthError2 (errors.tsx:9:11)     
at utils.tsx:17:14     
at auth0-provider.tsx:237:15     
at step (@auth0_auth0-react.js?v=9dbc3aa2:144:19)     
at Object.throw (@auth0_auth0-react.js?v=9dbc3aa2:91:14)     
at rejected (@auth0_auth0-react.js?v=9dbc3aa2:69:32)
```

Frontend Code:

```
const { isAuthenticated, user, getAccessTokenWithPopup } = useAuth0();
const { setUserDetails } = useContext(UserDetailContext);
const { mutate } = useMutation({
mutationKey: [user?.email],
mutationFn: () => createUser(user?.email),
});

useEffect(() => {
const getTokenAndRegister = async () => {
const res = await getAccessTokenWithPopup({
authorizationParams: {
audience: "http://localhost:8000",
scope: "openid profile email",
},
});
localStorage.setItem("access_token", res);
setUserDetails((prev) => ({ ...prev, token: res }));
console.log(res);
};
isAuthenticated && getTokenAndRegister();
}, [isAuthenticated]);
```

Backend Code:

auth0Config.js -->

```
import { auth } from "express-oauth2-jwt-bearer";

const jwtCheck = auth({
audience: "http://localhost:8000",
issuerBaseURL: "<--Confidential-->",
tokenSigningAlg: "RS256",
});

export default jwtCheck;
```

I am new to auth0 and and i have implemented the authentication in my application using auth0, but when i try to store the token i am not able to do so

Comment: Is you server running?

Comment: Yes my server is running